# How to fix: Error: Angular structure loaded both synchronously and asynchronously

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I just upgraded my Angular 6 project to Angular 11. This project has SSR implemented and here is the issue.

When I run `ng run myapp:server` I get this error:

```
✔ Server application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files | Names         |    Size
main.js             | main          | 4.06 kB

                    | Initial Total | 4.06 kB

Build at: 2021-04-22T14:02:16.388Z - Hash: 2a6aaefe9d15b8a7dedc - Time: 4907ms

Error: Angular structure loaded both synchronously and asynchronously
```

In my `angular.json` I have this code:

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myapp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          }
        },
  // ...
}
```

Any idea where I should check, update something?

Answer (score 10):

I had three time the same error,

### 1 : library wrong import

First, it was because I was creating a library, and one component of this library wasn't importing other module from the **same library** with the relative path.

```js
import { aModule } from '@my-lib/a.module.ts' // wrong

import { aModule } from '../../a.module.ts' // correct
```

### 2 : missing dependencies

One of my library did force to import some dependencies. one of them was `@videogular/ngx-videogular` which as of today only accept till the angular v11 but I'm using the angular v12.

I know it do works with angular v12 and to fix this, I had to force the install with the following `npm i @videogular/ngx-videogular --force`

### 3 : `enableIvy: true`

If you are using dependencies that do use `enableIvy: true` in their `tsconfig.lib.prod.json` then you also have to enable ivy on your own project. not doing so will create this error.

Also, if you do add a dependency that does, and other that don't, you'll also have the same error. So if you did had this error after having updated some external libraries, do control if they do or not had enabled ivy and go to a former version that didn't.

Comment: unfortunately my project isn't a library

Comment: @netdjw I face multiple time the same problem, maybe one of those may help you

Comment: 1 was my problem. But this applies to all modules, even ones you've created inside the library.

Comment: For me it was angular-split library v5.0.0. I downgraded to v4.0.0 and it works now.

Comment: You should never apply 3rd solution in an Angular 11 (library) project, as libraries published MUST be compiled using Angular ViewEngine, not Ivy. It is in version 12 that they will remove ViewEngine in favor of Ivy. 
https://sdtimes.com/softwaredev/angular-12-will-deprecate-view-engine-and-replace-it-with-ivy/

Comment: @netdjw Did you find the solution to your problem ?

Comment: no, and we droped SSR because of this issue

Comment: @netdjw What a shame.. I would bet though on `@nguniversal/express-engine` that do not use ivy (solution 3), which mean you shall not use enabled ivy component while using SSR. I head that Angular v13 will move forward to the ivy direction, and a lot of library are waiting this version to push everything as `enableIvy: true`. I would try it again in a few month.

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet Yes, it's a shame :D in our case dropping SSR was a painless decision. But thanks the infos.

Comment: Great answer! In my case, it was an external library, angular-split.

Answer (score 7):

Enabling Ivy solves the problem for me, add this angular Compiler Options to your tsconfig.app.json  :

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true, 
    "enableIvy": true
  },
```

Comment: @Michael.F please avoid these kind of comments, as you should find a way to fix the problem that didn't depend on wether you build before without Ivy. CI would directly be broken by your solution

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error in Angular project (not library) and issue was that I deleted some shared component from pproject but I forgot to remove it from appropriate module.

Comment: The cause for me was this one. I created a new component, which was added automatically to module. I deleted the component, but forgot to remove it from the module definition. How I wish Angular should have given a more appropriate message.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this issue with a library being updated to Angular 12. I fixed the issue by adding `"enableIvy": true` to my tsconfig.json

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
}
```

***AND*** I had to change my ngPackagr script to include the `-c tsconfig.json` argument:

```
ng-packagr -p lib/.../package.json -c tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem in my project after update Angular 9.1 to 11, when compiling a library. In my library folder in tsconfig.json file I deleted next angularCompileOptions

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
  "strictInjectionParameters": true,
  "enableIvy": "false"
}
```

and it started to work.

I don't know can I help this information somebody, but information by this issue very small. Therefore, I will publish it.

Comment: What does *"I deleted next angularCompileOptions"* mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67768272/16383608 I would say it is treated like enabling Ivy because of
"enableIvy":"false" instead of "enableIvy":false.
If you're facing this issue I would focus on your dependencies, dev dependencies and import of libraries. In my case, every time, it was lack of some dependencies because of wrong imports or incomplete package.json.

Answer (score 0):

We have `angularCompilerOptions.enableIvy = false`.

**Cause**: `export` keyword is required for factory functions to fix this error.

Example:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { JDbApiClient, LinksJDbContext } from '../shared';
import { JDbApiClientModule } from './jdb.api-client.module';


/* Error is HERE... -> */ export /*<- ...if keyword is missing */ function newLinksJDbContext(api: JDbApiClient) {
  return new LinksJDbContext(api);
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [JDbApiClientModule], 
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LinksJDbContext,
      useFactory: newLinksJDbContext,
      deps: [JDbApiClient],
    },
  ],  
})
export class LinksJDbContextModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone encounters this error while using [@ngrx/store](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/), check if reducer is being used correctly. As said in [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers) constant made with `createReducer` has to be wrapped in exported function and used in StoreModule. For example:

```js
const ngrxReducer = createReducer(
    INITIAL_STATE,
    on(someAction, (state, { someProperty }) => ({
        someProperty
    })
);

export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
    return ngrxReducer(state, action);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed external library docs and one of my imported Module used option object which property name was created with array [] syntax:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [MyLibrary.forFeature(MODALS)]
  ...
}) 


export enum MODAL_NAMES {
 ADVANCED_MODAL = 'ADVANCED_MODAL'
}

export const MODALS = {
 //error was here
 [MODAL_NAMES.ADVANCED_MODAL]: {
  ...
 }
};
```

So I changed it to string and it's did the trick

```
export const MODALS = {
     //no error: Angular structure loaded both synchronously and asynchronously
     'ADVANCED_MODAL': {
      ...
     }
    };
```

#### EDITED

Also faced this error during `ng build library` command. The reason behind this that i've used `pnpm install` instead of `npm install`. Deleting node_modules and running `npm install` once againg solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful for someone. I use NgRx in my application and faced with same error. I spent 1 day to find that I incorrectly provided reducers for my feature.
I provided refreshReducer as ActionReducer instead function that return state

```js
StoreModule.forFeature(REFRESH_FEATURE_KEY, refreshReducer)
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced same issue nut not in SSR.
I was getting same error with ng serve

to fixed this i just add @angular/cdk into dev dependency and issue got resolved.

```
npm i @angular/cdk
```

Comment: you can check this [repo](https://github.com/ooug/web)