# Angular structure loaded both synchronously and asynchronously when adding primeng tableModule

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, primeng, npm-package

I had the following error when loading TableModule from primeng into my components module file and trying to run 'npm run packagr':

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I found this solution, to change my primeng version primeng12 to primeng11.4.5. So I did that, but now I am getting the following error:

```
Angular structure loaded both synchronously and asynchronously
```

This is my components module file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HeaderComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, TableModule],
  exports: [HeaderComponent],
})
export class HeaderModule {} //RED LINE APPEARS HERE UNDER HEADERMODULE, BUT NOWHERE ELSE
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: @Drenai yes same error, but I tried all those solutions and non of them worked for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix: Error: Angular structure loaded both synchronously and asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67214967/how-to-fix-error-angular-structure-loaded-both-synchronously-and-asynchronousl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by changing prime ng version to 9.1.3 and installing angular cdk