# "Angular structure loaded both synchronously and asynchronously" error while setting up graphql apollo client in Angular

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo-client

> I am getting Angular structure loaded both synchronously and asynchronously error during apollo-client setup in angular. I tried all answers available in stackoverflow, still no luck. Need help here. Attached are the pieces of code used. I am getting error during code compilation. Once it is resolved, I should be able to get the console outputs. The query with api works fine, have checked in Postman. Only need to resolve the compilation error. The apollo client setup is as per the official documentation. https://apollo-angular.com/docs/get-started

```
cp-shared-lib-module.ts
------------------------
import { ProfileNameComponent } from './shared-features/profile-name/profile-name.component';
import { ProfileSummaryComponent } from './shared-features/profile-summary/profile- 
summary.component';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpResponseInterceptor } from './shared-services/response-interceptor/http-response-
import { GraphiComponent } from './graphi/graphi.component';
import { GraphService } from './graphi/graphi.service';
import { APOLLO_OPTIONS, ApolloModule, Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular/http';
import { InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ApolloModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild({ extend: true }),
  ],
  declarations: [
    GraphiComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpInterceptorService,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpResponseInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory(httpLink: HttpLink) {
        return {
          cache: new InMemoryCache(),
          link: httpLink.create({
          uri: 'https://grahphqldemo-dit.r3.pcf.dell.com/graphql',
          }),
        };
      },
      deps: [HttpLink],
    },
    GraphService
   ],
   exports: [
    GraphiComponent
  ],  
})
export class CpSharedLibModule {}

graphi.component.ts
--------------------
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Apollo, gql } from 'apollo-angular';
import { GraphService } from './graphi.service';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-graphi',
  templateUrl: './graphi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graphi.component.css']
})
export class GraphiComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string;
  id: number;
  currency: string;
  querySubscription: Subscription;
  query_data = gql`
  {
    bankAccount{
      name
      id
      currency
  }
  }
  `;
  constructor(private graphService: GraphService,
              private apollo: Apollo
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.querySubscription = this.apollo.watchQuery({
      query: this.query_data
    })
    .valueChanges.subscribe((response: any) => {
      if(response) {
        this.name = response.data.bankAccount.name;
        this.id = response.data.bankAccount.id;
        this.currency = response.data.bankAccount.currency;
        console.log(this.id, this.name, this.currency);
      }
      else {
        console.log('error for gql');
      }
    })
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.querySubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Comment: Does any of this solve your problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67482544/3565132

Comment: Haris Bouchlis, No tried all of them.

Comment: There's a problem with the module part. I tried commenting one /few lines of code to find the root cause. The error still persists. Keeping only the component file, build is successful. So, the component code is fine I guess. Also, tried creating a custom graphql module and imported in the cp-shared-lib-module.ts. Still no luck.

Comment: Also, I modified the useFactory method in NgModule as it was giving lambda expression error. This is the only change from the official documentation.

Comment: Finally!! resolved the error. SO  I was adding the APOLLO_OPTIONS in providers in one of my micro libraries. Instead I added the setup part(APOLLO_OPTIONS and HttpLink) in my main web(the one where all micro libs. are build files are pasted) and called the apollo client in the micro Lib where also I am rendering the component. Now, build is successful as well as I am able to console.log the output. That's how my UI application is structured.